# Filter childs not parents of relationship Coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter the child of relationship in coredata but the problem is that Coredata filters by parent and this is correct but it isn't filtering the childs.

**Model**:

```
Volumen <-->> MusicScore
```

I want filter the musicscore rows by volumen.

My NSPredicate is that:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(relation_music_score, $musicscore, ANY $musicscore.nameMusicScore CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0", searchStr];

self.collectionVolumen = [BOIVolumen MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```

CoreData get me all volumes that contains the name of music score searched but I want the all volumens with only the music score searched not all music score.

**Example**:

```
Volumens
  name = "One",
  etc..
  relation_music_score = NSOrderedSet

     Music Score (1)
       name = "One"

     Music Score (2)
       name = "two"

Volumens
  name = "Two",
  etc..
  relation_music_score = NSOrderedSet

     Music Score (3)
       name = "three"

     Music Score (4)
        name = "four"
```

When I'm searching the music score with name "two" I want this result:

```
Volumens
  name = "One",
  etc..
  relation_music_score = NSOrderedSet

Music Score (2)
  name = "two"
```

And the previos NSPredicate get me:

```
Volumens
  name = "One",
  etc..
  relation_music_score = NSOrderedSet

Music Score (1)
  name = "One"

Music Score (2)
  name = "two"
```

**EDIT**:

I'm trying the filter the relationship with this predicate and code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [self.collectionVolumen count]; i++) {
        BOIVolumen *volumen = [self.collectionVolumen objectAtIndex:i];
        NSOrderedSet *musicStore = [[self.collectionVolumen objectAtIndex:i] relation_music_score];

        NSPredicate *filterMusicScore = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameMusicScore CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchStr];
        NSOrderedSet *musicStoreTemporal = [musicStore filteredOrderedSetUsingPredicate:filterMusicScore];

        volumen.relation_music_score = musicStoreTemporal;
    }
```

and always I get this error **The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.** I was finding and I didn't found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate, though overly complicated, is working. You are getting the correct selection of `Volumen` entities. The found instance of course still has all the available relationships, so you have two choices:

- You either filter the relationships again e.g. with `filteredSetUsingPredicate:`,
- or you fetch the `MusicScore` entities in the first place rather than the `Volumen` entities.

I think the second option is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, I'm trying the filter the relationship but always I get the same error and I don't know what happens. I gonna edit my post for show you. Thanks again.